# If the difference between 2 numbers is between 1 and 100 it should run an if statement

Tags: c++

I'm not sure why the if statement saying the "numbers are close" is not running?

I've tested it with numbers to create a difference between 1-100.

Any ideas?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double num1, num2, difference;


    while(num1 != 100 || num2 != 200)
    {
        cout << "Enter a number:" << endl ;
        cin >> num1 ;
        cout << "Enter a 2nd number: " << endl ;
        cin >> num2 ;
        if (num1 == num2)
            { cout << "the numbers are equal" << endl ;
            }
        else if (num1 > num2)
        {   cout << "The larger number is num1:" << num1 << endl ;
            cout << "The smaller number is num2:" <<num2 << endl;
            difference = num1- num2;
           if (difference <100 && difference > 1)
            {
            cout << "Numbers are almost equal\n" ;
            }
            else
            {}
        }
    else if (num2 - num1)
        {   cout << "The larger number is num2:" << num2 << endl ;
            cout << "The smaller number is num1:" <<num1 << endl;
        }



    }
    return 0;
}
```

Kind regards,

Comment: `while(num1 != 100 || num2 != 200)` - undefined behaviour. Those variables are never initialised.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
difference = num1- num2;
```

you need

```
difference = fabs(num1- num2);
```

Otherwise, the test for "closeness" will work only when `num1` is greater than `num2`.

Also make sure that `num1` and `num2` are initialized before the `while` loop.

```
double num1 = 0;
double num2 = 0;
double difference = 0;  // Just for consistency

while ( ... )
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use `abs` to get the absolute value of the difference of the 2 numbers.

also your while look had some issues, mainly calling variables that hadn't been given a value yet try the code below, it should do what you're wanting to accomplish.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {

  bool again = true;

  while(again){
    double num1, num2, diffrence;
    cout << "Enter a Number: " << endl;
    cin >>num1; 
    cout << "Enter a 2nd Number: " << endl;
    cin >> num2;

    diffrence = abs(num1-num2);

    if(diffrence==0){
        cout << "the numbers are equal";
    }else{
      if(num1>num2){
        cout << "the larger number is num1: " << num1 << endl;
        cout << "the smaller number is num2: " << num2 << endl;
      }else{
        cout << "the larger number is num2: " << num2 << endl;
        cout << "the smaller number is num1: " << num1 << endl;
      }  
      if(diffrence<100){
        cout << "Numbers are almost equal\n";
      }else{
        cout << "Numbers are not even close";
      }
    }
    cout << "Try again (y/n)?" << endl;
    char response;
    cin >> response;
    if(tolower(response)=='n'){
      again = false;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

auto x = main();
```